# is PlayStore filtering devices if

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have integrated library which has following code on Gradle.

Unfortunately when I am changing abiFilters gralde build failing.

I am wondering is PlayStore going to filter and show apk only armeabi-v7a devices?

I want it will be available also on x86 devices.

```
 externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
                arguments "--jobs=${Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().toString()}"
            }
        }
```

Comment: I will suggest you to read this https://android.stackexchange.com/a/186348. I don't think x86 is still worthy of spending effort to support it.

Comment: @sunilsunny yeah x86 not worth to support but about x86-64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app relies on native libraries, but only has them in **armeabi-v7a**, many x86 devices will still be able to play it correctly via *houdini* emulator. This may be a significant performance hit, but more often than not, this is a price you are prepared to pay.

Such app will not run on x86 emulator.